# JS Issue with Accordion Script on WordPress involving initial background color

Tags: javascript, accordion

Got an issue where I have a JavaScript that is supposed to allow you to click a link on the home and it opens up a page with an Accordion (using the Elementor plugin) that opens up to one of the four panes depending on link.

That portion of the script works, but the background color for the active tab is always the first no matter which pane is open. It should add a class called elementor-acitve but it doesn't and I'm stumped as to why.

To see it in action, go to https://deganiagroup.com/ and scroll down to Services and click on any of the three links on the right which will open the second, third or final pane.

Here's my JS:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //get the hash tag
    //hash exist
    setTimeout(function () {
        var current = window.location.href
        var current = current.split('#tab')
        if (current.length > 1) {
        showAndScrollToTab($, current)
    }
    }, 200);
// change the browser url according to selected tab
    $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab]').click(function () {
        var current_location = window.location.href;
        current_location = current_location.split('#')
        window.location = current_location[0] + '#tab' + $(this).attr('data-tab')
    })
// activate tab also from anchor link in the same page
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        var anchorUrl = $(this).attr('href')
        var anchor = anchorUrl.split('#tab')
        if (anchor.length > 1) {
        showAndScrollToTab($, anchor)
        }
    })
})

function showAndScrollToTab($, current) {
    $('.elementor-tab-content').removeClass('elementor-active').css('display','none')
    $('.elementor-tab-content[data-tab="' + current[1] + '"]').addClass('elementor-active').css('display','block')
    $('.elementor-tab-content').hide();
    $('.elementor-tab-content[data-tab="'+current[1]+'"]').show();

    // scroll to
    var headerHeight = $('#header').height() // put here your header id to get its height.
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
scrollTop: $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab="' + current[1] + '"]').closest('.elementor-widget-wrap').offset().top - headerHeight }, 2000)
}
</script>
```

Comment: so after clicking next, the content background should change to black, and tab header should be something like green?

Answer (score 0):

when you laoding page with active you have to add `active class to tab header` your already activating tab via javascript. the changes you should make.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
        var current = window.location.href
        var current = current.split('#tab')
        if (current.length > 1) {
         $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab="' + current[1] + '"]').addClass('elementor-active');
         showAndScrollToTab($, current)
    }
    }, 200);
```

**UPDATE**

you can do that in 2 ways. change above code to

```
setTimeout(function () {
        var current = window.location.href
        var current = current.split('#tab')
        if (current.length > 1) {
           $('.elementor-accordion-item:first-child').find('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
           $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab="' + current[1] + '"]').addClass('elementor-active');
         showAndScrollToTab($, current)
    }
    }, 200);
```

the second way you should loop

Comment: That almost worked. The correct pane did open up and it's green, but unfortunately, the first pane is also green as well. So unless, you click the link to open the first pane, you'll have two green panes.